# Android : Differentiate between a flick and swipe

Tags: android, android-gesture

I'm trying to do differentiate between swipe and a flick action. For flick I'm using `onFling` method of `SimpleGestureControl` and `ACTION_MOVE` to detect horizontal swipe. I'm able to achieve the almost desired result but when I do long flick(i.e. touching screen for a bit long) it does take it as flick but my scroll function is also called. How do I differentiate them in a better way?